# When opening multiple pages, the localStorage value is deleted before another page can get it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I have 2 pages. On the first one, I'm clicking a link (`<a href>` - a tag button) and the js code is taking its text value and saving it into the localStorage. Since it's a link, a new page is opened. On that page, I want to retrieve the localStorage value, execute the AJAX request and remove the value from the localStorage. So, the new page loads, retrieves the value from the LS, executes the AJAX code and sets the value to "". The problem is that when I'm clicking tags multiple times, the value from the previous tag click is removed before the next page can retrieve it. So it looks something like this:
Click -> save value -> open new page -> retrieve the value -> second click -> save value -> execute AJAX (1st click) -> open new page (2nd click) -> delete the value (1st click) -> can't retrieve the value from the 2nd click.
Here's some code:

```
// 1st page
$(function(){ 
    $('.tag').on('click auxclick', function(){
        let tag = $(this).text();
        localStorage.setItem("searchTag", tag);
    });
});
```

```
// 2nd page
        let storedTag = localStorage.getItem("searchTag");

        // Send the serach form when the page is loaded
        $(document).ready(function(){

                // Get the tag from the localStorage and search it 
 
            setTimeout(function(){
                // insert value from the localStorage to the input
                document.getElementById("search-bar").value = storedTag;
                
                var search_input = $("#search-bar").val();


                // The search-bar should be the only data c:
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'Php/display-recipe-list.php',
                    data: {"search-bar": storedTag},
                    success: function(response){
                        $(".recipe-list").html(response);
                        switchTypes();
                        
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            localStorage.setItem("searchTag", "");
                        }, 10);
                    }
                });
            }, 25);
        });
```

As you can see, I've been trying to fix this with setTimeout, but it's only delaying the inevitable. Without timeouts, the value would still be deleted (code takes time to execute, so when spam clicking, it would not help). How can I fix this? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This seems like a design issue. Why involve local storage at all? Why not make the tag part of the URL as a parameter?

Comment: Where would NOT clearing the localStorage present a problem for you?

Comment: @mplungjan I have to remove the value for the localStorage, because I want it so when I click the tag, it takes me to the new page and searches it (ajax) and then when I reload the page I don't want this tag to be searched.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not saying it's a perfect solution, but why would it be a design issue? Genuine question.

Comment: Well you've already figured out that it's problematic. It's not really possible to synchronize between separate HTTP requests. By having the parameter be part of the request data (and part of the response) for each request separately, the responses have independent values.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = () => localStorage.setItem("searchTag", "");`

Comment: @Pointy I changed the code to use the URL parameter and I think it works perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it would work, the user can auxclick the tag (scroll click) and open multiple tabs at once. I changed the code to use URL parameters, but thank you for your help!